# resetting CDbConnection in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am running a php gearman worker which establishes the connection to the database. However, the problem is that after around 8 hours, the mysql connection disconnects, and my worker crashes. So, I wanted to disconnect and make a new connection to the database again.

I am using CDbConnection to connect to the database in Yii, and was expecting "setActive(false)" to do the trick for me. Here below I am "explicitly disconnecting" and the making a db query....expecting my query to throw an exception, but I am surprised to see that "setActive" makes no impact at all and my query goes successfully.

```
    //if it fails then reconnect to the database
    Yii::app()->db->setActive(false);
    try {
        $model = MyModel::model()->findByPk(10);
        var_dump($model);
    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo "got exception -- ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
        Yii::app()->db->setActive(false);
        Yii::app()->db->setActive(true);

        // I also tried Yii::app()->db->active = true/false

        $model = MyModel::model()->findByPk(10);
        var_dump($model);
    }
```

How do I disconnect and reconnect to my database with CdbConnection?

Comment: Any chance the result is cached and therefore closing the connection doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi Jon....how do I find out if the result is cached and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in the trace log, I'm pretty sure it actually closes the connection, but then reopens it in `CDbConnection->createCommand()` when you execute a query.

Comment: ohh okay....you are right....it does do a "setActive(true)" before making the query. That is why this query is working fine....but then how to I test the "mysql server has gone away error", because in that case when I try to make a query, then I get the error "MYSQL server has gone away"

Comment: The "MySQL server has gone away" is normally due to a timeout [Timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html). Try setting the timeout very low [link to guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), or kill the connection [link to guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html)